# git: how push to two repositories, but ignore specific directories for given repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I have several exposure sensitive files, however "most of all project files" (ignoring specific directories) need to be available to an "homologation server" and all files available to a production server.

I don't know if it's the best solution, but I imagine it would be something like this:
Upload (push) all files to "repository 1" which is used by the "production server",
Upload all files, with the "exception of some specific directories" for "repository 2" which is used by the "homologation server".

Currently I have to copy the development files to another directory, and from that other directory, remove the sensitive files and from that directory send to the "homologation server (repository 2)".

**Objective:**

From the development computer, upload (push) all project files to the "repository 1" and at the same time upload all files, but from the same development computer, upload to the repository 2, but with the exception of "some specific directories", Thus, the approval server will only download the appropriate files from its respective repository

Below is an example of what I imagine, but as I only know the git essentials, I don't know if it's possible.

For example, from my computer, I send all files to both repositories, but in "repository 2", in this example, the directory "resources" would not be sent and/or ignored.

[image: git push]

Comment: Git pushes *commits*, not files or directories. Make sure you have the desired commits—remember that each one holds a full snapshot of *every* file that it holds (`git ls-tree -r <hash>` will show this)—and then be extremely careful not to push the unwanted commits to the unwanted location. As a rule, however, you should never store *any* sensitive file in *any* repository that may *ever* become public. Consider storing the sensitive files in a completely separate, well-guarded repository.

Comment: In your context I would rather have something handle this outside of git because you won't be able to easily guarantee that all people working on the repo will never push some directories. For instance a hook on repo1 that triggers a copy to repo1 without the unwanted folders.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not offer a way to omit pushing certain directories.  The object ID for each commit is dependent on the metadata for that commit, including its parents and the root tree for the data representing that commit.  If you change the contents of each commit to exclude some content, then you will end up with two completely different histories.

What you may wish to do instead is to deploy changes to each server using a tarball created by `git archive`.  You can then filter the tarball using `bsdtar`, like so: `bsdtar -czf filtered.tar.gz --exclude resources @original.tar.gz`.  This filtered tarball can then be used to deploy changes to the remote system that you don't want to have certain content.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as I don't know about this git feature, I will search to see if I can make use of it